# how to add, edit, view using translate behaviour with model relationship like belongsTo, hasMany in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

How to add, edit, view using Translate Behavior with model relationship in Cakephp-2.0 ?

My code for add:

```
public function add() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Faq->create();        
        if ($this->Faq->saveMany($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The faq has been saved', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The faq could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
        $languages = $this->Language->getlangs();
        if(is_array($this->{$this->modelClass}->belongsTo)) {
            foreach($this->{$this->modelClass}->belongsTo as $relation => $model) {
                foreach($languages as $lang){
                    $this->{$this->modelClass}->$model['className']->locale = $lang['Language']['language_locale'];
                    $faqCategories[$lang['Language']['language_locale']] = $this->Faq->FaqCategory->find('list', array('conditions' => array('FaqCategory.is_active' => 1), 'recursive' => 1));
                }
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('faqCategories'));


}
```

My code for edit:

```
public function edit($id = null) {

    if (!$this->Faq->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid faq'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Faq->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The faq has been saved', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The faq could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Faq.' . $this->Faq->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Faq->find('first', $options);
    }
    $faqCategories = $this->Faq->FaqCategory->find('list', array('conditions' => array('FaqCategory.is_active' => 1)));
    $this->set(compact('faqCategories'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cakebake is generally easy way in cake php. and it vey simple using from command line

[image]

make 2 tables

1. departement and 2 is student so student table in dept id as foreign key relationships

Answer (score 0):

TranslateBehavior is very simply to use because it is handled at the Model level.

Add it to your model like this:

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Translate' => array('fields','to','translate')
    )
);
```

This will automatically handle all CRUD operations properly and store translations in the db.

Pre-req is to initialize the i18n database tables. See ref here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html